# Vim error E492: Not an editor command: dd

Tags: vim, ubuntu

I started learning vim today and installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Now, when I try to do something like `:5dd` it gives me the not an editor command error. I'm not sure why this is.

Am I doing anything wrong? I looked at tutorials and everywhere I look I see that 5dd is a valid command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:5dd` is not the same as just `5dd`. You use `5dd` in *normal* mode to delete 5 lines, you can use `:5delete` or just `:5d` to do the same thing as a command.

Comment: "You use 5dd in normal mode to delete 5 lines, you can use :5d to do the same thing as a command" Not quite. `:5d` will delete line number 5, whereas `5dd` will delete 5 lines from the current cursor position downwards.